# Trying to sort an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array least to greatest and i am really lost....

Here is what i have so far:

```
 int temp, temp2;
    for (int x = 0; x < array_size; x++)
    {
            temp=a[x];

            for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] < temp)
                {
                    temp2=a[i];
                    a[i]=temp;
                    a[x]=temp2;
                }
            }
    }
```

updated: still not working and i have to use code.

```
int temp, temp2, x=-1;
for (int x = 0; x < array_size; x++)
{
        temp=a[x];

        for (int i = x+1; i < array_size; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < temp)
            {
                temp2=a[i];
                a[i]=temp;
                a[x]=temp2;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: When you say "i have to use code", what do you mean?  That you can't use any library functions?  Then your question is really about how to do a bubble sort in C++?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832765/whats-a-bubble-sort/832777#832777

Comment: yeah i mean like i have to code it myself i cant use library functions as you showed me below.

Comment: Removed `possible-homework` tag - see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ - From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.

Comment: I know that, Alec, I can see the history. I wasn't taking a swipe at you, just telling everyone why I did it. Cheers.

Comment: Visit http://www.sorting-algorithms.com to view the implementation, and graphical representation of your favourite algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the STL [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) algorithm.

In case you really want to hand code it, you may want to make some changes:

In the inner `for` loop, change

```
int i = 0
```

to

```
int i = x + 1
```

Also, reassign `temp` to `a[i]` inside the `if`.

---

Full code below:

```
// Arun Saha, 2010-Oct-20
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983541/trying-to-sort-an-array

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void
mysort( int * a, size_t array_size ) {

    for( size_t i = 0; i < array_size; ++i ) {

        int minSoFar = a[i];

        for (size_t j = i+1; j < array_size; ++j ) {

            if( a[j] < minSoFar ) {

                minSoFar = a[j];

                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i]    = a[j];
                a[j]    = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int
main() {

   int x[] = {40, 60, 10, 30, 20, 50};
   const size_t N = sizeof( x ) / sizeof( int );

   for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
       cout << x[ i ] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   mysort( x, N );

   for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
       cout << x[ i ] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why would i want to set a[i]=a[i]?

Comment: I said, `temp = a[i]` inside the `if() { ..}`

Comment: @Alec: I took your code and made few tweaks to make it work. Check out the link to codepad, which has the full code and output of an example.

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot! Exactly what i needed to see to understand.

Comment: @Arun, it's usually a better idea to post the code _here_ so as to keep SO as self-contained as possible. I always assume that every other site on the net will disappear (a reason I don't like nothing-but-a-link or LMGTFY answers).

Comment: @paxdiablo: I cent-percent agree with you. However, whenever the code snippet is long and a scrollbar appears on the side, I hesitate to post it :(. Thank you for making the edit. I would keep your advice in mind.

Comment: @Arun, sometimes I insert a `&nbsp;` line in the code (needs a blank line after it to get back into code mode) to ensure no scroll bar appears (generally only for relatively short code segments, say two pages in a scroll area). Long code, I'll leave alone so it doesn't pollute the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Unless this is homework and you're limited in which functions you can use:

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::sort(a,a+array_size);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use one of the library-provided sort routines but, for what it's worth, the canonical bubble sort can be done as follows:

```
def bubblesort (array, count):
    limit = count - 2
    didSwap = true
    while (didSwap) {
        didSwap = false
        for pos = 0 to limit:
            if array[pos] > array[pos+1]:
                temp = array[pos]
                array[pos] = array[pos+1]
                array[pos+1] = temp
                didSwap = true
            endif
        endfor
        limit = limit - 1
    endwhile
enddef
```

I would only use this where library-provided routines are not usable for some reason and, even then, only for small data sets.

It's relatively efficient (as far as bubble sort goes) since it doesn't re-check elements that have already been placed in the correct position (each iteration moves one more element to its correct position at the top of the list, hence the use of `limit`), and will exit after an iteration in which no swaps are done (i.e., the list is sorted).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at C's 'qsort' method? That'll sort your array.

C++ has its own built-in sort function too, as part of its standard library.

Can you not use either of those?

In your code, the inner loop ought to start with `int i = x+1;` rather than with i starting at 0.